# A box contains some red and yellow balls. If one red ball is removed ...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, contest-math, solution-verification

A box contains some red and some yellow balls. If one red ball is removed, one seventh of the remaining balls would be red; if one yellow ball is removed, one-sixth of the remaining balls would be red. If n denotes the total number of balls in the box, then the sum of the digits of n is:

I'm pretty sure that n=43. But the answer given is that sum of digits is 6. Can you please check my answer.

Comment: Could you show us your work?

Comment: I got n=43 also.

Comment: The answer given is wrong probably. $n$ is indeed $43$.

Comment: Yes, red balls$=7$, yellow balls$=36$, total $43$.

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer given is wrong, in fact let $T$ the total number of balls and let $R$ the number of red ones. So, we have:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
R-1=\frac{1}{7}(T-1)
\\ R=\frac{1}{6}(T-1)
\end{matrix}\right.$$
Substracting the first to the second, we have:
$$1=(T-1)\cdot\frac{1}{42}\leftrightarrow T=43$$
So, the sum of digits of $T$ is $7\neq6$.

Comment: @Sujal Motagi: if this answer has been useful, maybe a $+1$ or a favourite answer?